# My code outputs an error, I don't understand why

Tags: python

I'm trying to calculate something, but the code outputs an error

I have even tried splitting the operation in many single parts, to not do all at one time, I have tried by setting and int() output, but it doesn't work too

```
import math

x_coo = 20
y_coo = 30
x = 50
y = 80

def distance(x_coo,y_coo,x,y):
    dist = math.sqrt((e.x_coo-a.x)**2 + (e.y_coo-a.y)**2)

force = (81*24*25)/ (distance(e.x_coo,e.y_coo, a.x,a.y)^2)
print(force)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Comment: You aren't returning anything from `distance`. Also, `^` is XOR not exponentiation

Comment: What are `e` and `a´?

Comment: Also your parameters do not seem to match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to return the result of the operation inside the function:

```
import math

x_coo = 20
y_coo = 30
x = 50
y = 80

def distance(x_coo,y_coo,x,y):
    dist = math.sqrt((e.x_coo-a.x)**2 + (e.y_coo-a.y)**2)
    return dist

force = (81*24*25)/ (distance(e.x_coo,e.y_coo, a.x,a.y)^2)
print(force)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a value from the function `distance`. Python loves returning values, and if you do not declare what your function returns, Python assumes you want to return `None`.

Here's what you should have:

```
def distance(x_coo,y_coo,x,y):
    dist = math.sqrt((e.x_coo-a.x)**2 + (e.y_coo-a.y)**2)
    return dist
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed `return` on `distance()`, i.e.:

```
def distance(x_coo,y_coo,x,y):
    return math.sqrt((e.x_coo-a.x)**2 + (e.y_coo-a.y)**2)
```